# Why it is this program not finding pairs in an array that sum to a given value?

Tags: c, matrix

My code so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a[5][5] = {
        {-1, 2, 3, 4 },
        { 5, 3, -2, 1 },
        { 6, 7, 2, -3 },
        { 2, 9, 1, 4 },
        { 2, 1, -2, 0 }
    };
    int sum = 11;
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            if (a[i][j] + a[j][i] == sum && i != j) {
                printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to find pairs with given sum such that elements of pair are in different rows.

Comment: You should tell us which elements your program should find. If you print all combinations, you will see that no sum is `11`: http://ideone.com/hYa7ZI

Comment: Because, `c/c++` is UB.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Yes, that's my favourite; C / C++ is UB in C and C++.

Comment: @Ravi: You'll attract fewer downvotes if you choose either C or C++. The languages started to diverge from 1999.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `a` is a 5x5 array with an extra column of zeros. That has a benign effect.

**Your algorithm is faulty!** If you adjust your conditional to

```
if (a[i][j] + a[j][i] == sum && i != j) {
    printf("Yes %d %d\n", i, j);
} else {
    printf("No %d %d\n", i, j);
}
```

it becomes obvious that you are not considering the sum of every possible pair. The ones that get missed out are, by coincidence, the pairs that sum to 11.

Essentially you need 4 nested loops, and you need to consider every number with every other number in the array.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should notice that you defined a `5X5 int array` but only filled in 4 `ints` in each sub-array. If you would print out your array, you'll see the values are:

```
-1      2       3       4       0
5       3       -2      1       0
6       7       2       -3      0
2       9       1       4       0
2       1       -2      0       0
```

I guess that wasn't your intention...

Now, for your question - you want to find `a[i][j] + a[j][i] == 11` for `i!=j`. The reason you get no output is because there aren't such elements that satisfy your conditions in the array you defined.

Answer (score 0):

if you want "pairs with given sum such that elements of pair are in different rows." then you should try code like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  const int rows = 5;
  const int cols = 4;
  int sum = 11;
  int i, j, i1, j1;
  int a[rows][cols] =
  {
    {-1, 2, 3, 4 },
    { 5, 3, -2, 1 },
    { 6, 7, 2, -3 },
    { 2, 9, 1, 4 },
    { 2, 1, -2, 0 }
  };
  for(i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < cols; j++)
      for(i1 = i + 1; i1 < rows; i1++)
        for(j1 = 0; j1 < cols; j1++)
          if(a[i][j] + a[i1][j1] == sum)
             printf("[%d %d](%d); [%d %d](%d)\n", i, j, a[i][j], i1, j1, a[i1][j1]);
}
```

Comment: Not your fault but this answer is now invalidated since the OP clarified it's C not C++.

Comment: @Bathsheba The OP did not clarify it, πάντα ῥεῖ choose (by unknown reasons) that it is C.

Comment: @mch what "so on is"? is there something other wrong?

Comment: @AustinPowers: Try not to adopt the mantra "if it compiles, ship it"; not until you're an equity partner at a hedge fund, anyway. Note that this will not compile with current C compilers.

Comment: @Bathsheba what do you mean?

Comment: @Bathsheba this question was tagged as c++ at the moment i post my answer

Comment: @AustinPowers "and so on..." means the other 3 loops. Now your code works, but I would declare `a` and `sum` also `constexpr`

Comment: All you need to do is change the `constexpr`.

Comment: so you downvoted becaas someone changed tag from c++ to c... ok nice community here

Comment: I have not (yet) downvoted. Yes, this community is quite robust, but we're nice really.

Comment: @Bathsheba i know) im nice))

Answer (score 0):

Below program will solve your problem,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int a[5][5] = {
        {-1, 2, 3, 4 },
        { 5, 3, -2, 1 },
        { 6, 7, 2, -3 },
        { 2, 9, 1, 4 },
        { 2, 1, -2, 0 }
    };
        int sum=11,i,j,k,l;
        for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
                for(j=i+1;j<5;j++)
                {
                        for(k=0;k<5;k++)
                        {
                                for(l=0;l<5;l++)
                                {
                                        if(a[i][k]+a[j][l]==sum)
                                                printf("a[%d][%d] = %d\ta[%d][%d] = %d\n",i,k,a[i][k],j,l,a[j][l]);
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```